# Import gapi.auth2 in angular 2 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, google-api-js-client

I tried to import some classes or function from Google gapi.auth2 in typescript. But below code never works even I correctly added the gapi.auth2 types in typings directory.

```
import { GoogleAuth } from 'gapi.auth2';
```

I always got error:

```
Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'gapi.auth2'
```

Shall I use some relative directory searching, such as `../../typings/gapi.auth2`?

Or maybe the way I am using the gapi is totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the import instructions https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 74):

To use `gapi` and `gapi.auth` with Angular2, install the type script definitions using NPM.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

This will install two packages, [@types/gapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi) and [@types/gapi.auth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi.auth2) to the `node_modules` folder and save the configuration in `package.json`.

Inspect your `node_modules` folder to check they install correctly. If your Angular app is called "main-app", you should see:

```
main-app/
  node_modules/
    @types/
      gapi/
      gapi.auth2/
```

The [red pill and blue pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill) scenario:

- If have have NOT provided any [types compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#types) there should be no need to explicitly add `gapi` or `gapi.auth2` to the `"types": []` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` because

1. By default all visible `@types` packages are included during compilation.
2. Packages in `node_modules/@types` (of any enclosing folder) are considered visible.

- **But**. If `types` is already specified, the [TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#types) explains that you MUST add `gapi` or `gapi.auth2` otherwise they will NOT be included by default.  In this secnario, edit `tsconfig.json` to include new `gapi` and `gapi.auth2` types:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     "types": ["jest", "lodash", "gapi", "gapi.auth2"]
    }
}
```

At this point, if you feel motivated enough, you could read [Typescript Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), you can skip straight to **How Node.js resolves modules**:

> *Node will look for your modules in special folders named*
> *`node_modules`. A `node_modules` folder can be on the same level as the*
> *current file, or higher up in the directory chain. Node will walk up*
> *the directory chain, looking through each `node_modules` until it finds*
> *the module you tried to load.*

For this reason, you shouldn't need to add a reference to the type definitions in your Angular2 Service or Component (or wherever you're using `gapi` or `gapi.auth2`).

However, if you do add a reference to the `gapi` or `gapi.auth2` TypeScript definitions, it must reference the `.ts` file installed using `npm install` (note, you must keep the `///` oherwise you'll get an error):

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts" />
```

The path is relative, so yours may differ depending on where your `.ts` file is relative to where you installed the TypeScript definitions.

Whether you added an explicit reference or used TypeScript's Node module resolution mechanism, you still need to declare your variables in your `.ts` file so Angular knows about the window `gapi` variable at compile time. Add `declare var gapi: any;` to your `.ts` file but do *not* place it within a class definition. I put mine just below any imports:

```
// You may not have this explicit reference.
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts" />
import { NgZone, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
declare var gapi: any;
```

**Working with Other JavaScript Libraries** in [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) is worth reading to understand what we're getting with all this work.

Next, load the `gapi` client from your own function (possibly in an Angular Service):

```
 loadClient(): Promise<any> {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         this.zone.run(() => {
                gapi.load('client', {
                    callback: resolve,
                    onerror: reject,
                    timeout: 1000, // 5 seconds.
                    ontimeout: reject
                });
         });
    });
}
```

This function is non-trivial, here's why...

Firstly, note we're calling [gapi.load](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiloadlibraries-callbackorconfig) with a **configuration object** and not a **callback**. The [GAPI reference](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiloadlibraries-callbackorconfig) states either can be used:

- A callback function that is called when the libraries have finished
  loading.
- An object encapsulating the various configuration parameters
  for this method. Only callback is required.

Using a configuration option allows us to **reject** the Promise when loading the library times-out, or just errors. In my experience, loading the library fails more often than initializing it - which is why configuration object is better than just a callback.

Secondly, we're wrapping `gapi.load` in

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  // gapi.load
});
```

[NgZone.run is documented](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) and states

> Running functions via `zone.run` allows you to reenter Angular zone from
> a task that was executed outside of the Angular zone [...]

This is exactly what we want since the call to `gapi.load` leaves the Angular zone. Omitting this can leave to very funky results that can be hard to debug.

Thirdly, `loadClient()` returns a promise that is resolved - allowing the caller to choose how they handle `gapi.load`. For example if our `loadClient` method belonged to an Angular service, `apiLoaderServce`, a component may use `ngOnInit` to load `gapi`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiLoaderService.loadClient().then(
        result => this.apiLoaded = true,
        err => this.apiLoaded = false
    );
}
```

Once `gapi.load` has been called, `gapi.client` will be ready and you should use it to initializes the JavaScript client with you API key, OAuth client ID, scope, and API discovery document(s):

```
initClient(): Promise<any> {
    var API_KEY = // Your API key.
    var DISCOVERY_DOC = // Your discovery doc URL.
    var initObj = {
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'discoveryDocs': [DISCOVERY_DOC],
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            gapi.client.init(initObj).then(resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}
```

Notice our friend [NgZone.run](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) is used once again to ensure the Angular Zone is re-entered.

In practice, I add `loadClient()` and `initClient()` to an Angular Service. In a high-level Angular component (usually just below the app-component) I load and initialize in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiLoaderService.loadClient().then(
        result => {
            this.apiLoaded = true;
            return this.apiLoaderService.initClient()
        },
        err => {
            this.apiFailed = true;
        }
    ).then(result => {
        this.apiReady = true;
    }, err => {
        this.apiFailed = true;
    });
}
```

Lastly, you need to add the gapi script file to your file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

You must not use the `async` **or** `defer` attributes since they will cause the Angular world to enter before the gapi library has loaded.

```
<!-- This will not work. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

I previously suggested keeping page-load speeds fast by loading a local, minified copy of the [gapi library](https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) in the `/main-app/src/assests` folder and importing:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="assets/api.js"></script>
```

However, I **strongly** recommend **not doing** this. Google may update https://apis.google.com/js/api.js and your client will break. I have been caught-out by this twice. In the end it was better just to import from `//apis.google.com/js/` and keep it as a blocking call.

Comment: After you've installed `@types/gapi` and `@types/gapi.auth2`, how do you use those types in your code? For example, you defined the promise as `Promise<any>`. How could I do something like `Promise<GoogleAuth>`?

Comment: @zanderle use it as `gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth`, also, If you, like me, started a new project with angular-cli, webpack should be crying about not finding the gapi namespace, add the types to tsconfig.app.json. since the angular team decided they didn't need automatic `../node_modules/@types` inclusions, which messes up webpack when it's doing bundles.

Comment: First of all thank you a lot for this in-depth walkthrough. Adding to this beautiful work, you can also directly [reference an @types package](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-) by using `/// <reference types="gapi" />`.

Comment: thanks a ton @Jack , this answer still works (and teaches a lot) as of Dec 2019. :)

Comment: tried everything without sucess error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'gapi' this thing must had change or something

Comment: @JBarros35 Can you link a Stackblitz?

Answer (score 15):

This is modified from [@Jack's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828547/jack) answer to use the RxJS library. While the original question asks for Angular 2, I'm using Angular 5 here in case anyone's working with an updated version.

1. The first step is the same, downloading the gapi types with npm.

   ```
   npm install --save @types/gapi
   npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
   ```
2. You will need to update your tsconfig.json. If you're having issues, you may also need to update tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json. They inherit from tsconfig.json, but if you specify types, I think they may overwrite the base. Snippet below:

   ```
   "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types"
   ],
   "types": [
     "gapi",
     "gapi.auth2"
   ],
   "lib": [
     "es2017",
     "dom"
   ]
   ```
3. Add a reference to Google's `platform.js`. I put mine in `index.html`. I left out `async` and `defer` as [@Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828547/jack) recommended.

   ```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
   ```
4. Next create an authentication service. The complete code is here:

   ```
   import { Injectable, NgZone, Output } from '@angular/core';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
   import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { User } from './User';

   @Injectable()
   export class AuthenticatorService {
       public auth2: any;
       public user$: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
       public isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
       public isLoaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

       constructor(private zone: NgZone, private http: HttpClient) { }

       validateToken(token: string): Observable<User> {
           return this.http.get<User>(`http://yourServer:3000/validationApi/${token}`);
       }

       signIn(): void {
           this.auth2.signIn().then(user => {
               this.validateToken(user.getAuthResponse().id_token).subscribe(user => {
                   this.zone.run(() => {
                       this.user$.next(user);
                       this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
                   });
               },
                   (err) => {
                       console.error(err);
                   });
           });
       };

       signOut(): void {
           this.auth2.signOut().then(() => {
               this.zone.run(() => {
                   this.isLoggedIn$.next(false);
                   this.user$.next(null);
               });
           },
               (err) => {
                   console.error(err);
               });
       }

       loadAuth2(): void {
           gapi.load('auth2', () => {
               gapi.auth2.init({
                   client_id: 'yourClientId',
                   fetch_basic_profile: true
               }).then((auth) => {
                   this.zone.run(() => {
                       this.auth2 = auth;
                       this.isLoaded$.next(true);
                   });
               },
               );
           });
       }
   }
   ```

We have a lot happening here. Start by taking notice of the RxJS BehaviorSubjects. We'll be using these to notify our components of changes.  Our `loadAuth2` function uses Google's library to get a `gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth` object. If you need more information on Google's authentication library please check out [their introduction](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) or [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams). Note we're using `this.zone.run` once we get our `GoogleAuth` object back. **Running the entire function in an `NgZone` led to unexpected behavior for me.** Next we take an RxJS `BehaviorSubject` `isLoaded$` and set the value to true. You'll see similar behavior in the `signIn()` and `signOut()` functions- taking the results and running them in an `NgZone` and updating our appropriate `BehaviorSubject`.

5. Now that we have our service, it's time to use it. We'll create a component for signing in and out. The code's below:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { AuthenticatorService } from  '../authenticator.service'
   import { User } from '../User';


   @Component({
   selector: 'sign-in',
   template: `
       <ng-container *ngIf="authIsLoaded">
            <button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" (click)="signIn()">Sign In With Google</button>
           <button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
       </ng-container>
       <h2 *ngIf="authIsLoaded && isLoggedIn"> Signed in as {{user.name}} </h2>`
   })
   export class GoogleAuthenticatorComponent implements OnInit {

   public authIsLoaded: boolean = false;
   public isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
   public user: User;

   constructor(private authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService) { }

       signIn(): void {
       this.authenticatorService.signIn();
       };

       signOut(): void {
       this.authenticatorService.signOut();
       }

       ngOnInit() {
       this.authenticatorService.isLoaded$.subscribe( value => {
           this.authIsLoaded = value;
       });

       this.authenticatorService.isLoggedIn$.subscribe( value => {
           this.isLoggedIn = value;
       });

       this.authenticatorService.user$.subscribe( value => {
           this.user = value;
       });

       this.authenticatorService.loadAuth2();
       }
   }
   ```

The most important part here is the `ngOnInit` implementation. This is where we'll subscribe to the AuthenticatorService's changes and update the view accordingly.

Hope these steps help someone out there to set up gapi.auth2 in their project.

Comment: upvoted for angular implementation. I know I'm a little late to the party, but is it possible for you to provide a simple repo link with a working example? I am struggling to use gapi calendar and any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is `User`?

Comment: Can you please describe 'User' object?

Comment: User can be anything... I got this to work by just stripping out the ValidateToken method (In my own use case, I'm validating via aws DynamoDB api - not HttpClient), and creating an empty user class: export class User { }.