# Google API Endpoints using Javascript client library as an Angular 2 Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-api-client, angular2-services

I am using Google API Javascript library in my Angular 2 application. I have created a service which is injected in components. Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const url = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=__onGoogleLoaded';
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAPIService {
 public client: any;
 public calculatorService: any;
 public actionService: any;
loadAPI: Promise<any>
      constructor(){
        this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
          window['__onGoogleLoaded'] = (ev) => {
            console.log('gapi loaded');
            resolve(window['gapi']);
            this.client = window['gapi'].client;
            this.loadEndPoints('{Endpoint URL}/_ah/api');
          }
          this.loadScript();
        });

      }

      doSomethingGoogley(){
        return this.loadAPI.then((gapi) => {
          console.log(gapi);
        });
      }

      loadScript(){
        console.log('loading..')
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = url;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);

      }

      loadEndPoints(apiRoot) {
  // Loads the OAuth and calculatorendpoint APIs asynchronously, and triggers login
  // when they have completed.
  var apisToLoad;
  var callback = function() {
    console.log('API Loaded '+apisToLoad);
    if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
      //this.endpoint1= this.client.endpoint1; //Doesn't Work
      //this.endpoint2= this.client.endpoint2; 
    }

  }

  apisToLoad = 3; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
  this.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', callback);  
  this.client.load('endpoint1', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
  this.client.load('endpoint2','v1',callback,apiRoot);

  }
}
```

**I have three  questions:**

1. How do I get the endpoints gapi.client.endpoint1 as a public variable in the service?
2. How do I call the methods in the api? In javascript, u can jst call gapi.client.endpoint1.method().execute()
3. How do I make this service singleton?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is the working version of the service. I use it as provider in my Root module. thus, its available as singleton throughout the application.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const url = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=__onGoogleLoaded';
const gapiOnLoaded = '__onGoogleLoaded';
const clientName = 'gapi';
const endpointhost = '[HTTPS URL FOR ENDPOINTS]';
const apiEndPoint = endpointhost + '/_ah/api';
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAPIService {
  private gapi: any;
  private loadAPI: Promise<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
        window[gapiOnLoaded] = (ev) => {
        this.gapi = window[clientName];
        // Loads the OAuth and other APIs asynchronously, and triggers login
        // when they have completed.
        let apisToLoad;
        let callback = function() {
        if (--apisToLoad === 0) {
            resolve(window[clientName]);
          }
        };
        apisToLoad = 3; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
        this.gapi.load('client:auth2', callback);
        this.gapi.client.load('[ENDPOINT_1_NAME]', 'v1', callback, apiEndPoint);
        this.gapi.client.load('[ENDPOINT_2_NAME]', 'v1', callback, apiEndPoint);
      };
      this.loadScript();
    });
  }

  public GetClient(): any {
        return   this.loadAPI.then((res) => {
              return this.gapi;
          });
  }

  private loadScript()  {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = url;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

Inject this service in other services. I created a service for each of the endpoints.

```
@Injectable()
export class Endpoint1Service {
    private gapi: any;
    constructor(private googleApiService: GoogleAPIService) {
    }

    public isLoad() {
        return this.googleApiService.GetClient().then((gapi) => {
                this.gapi = gapi;
                return true;
            });
    }

    public action(data: DataType){
        this.gapi.client.endpointname.apimethod(data).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by your first question? It looks like you already have a `const url = ...` to keep track of the google api url. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I have multiple endpoints.. so i wanted to assign these to separate public variables.. so that I can use them in components as myservice.endpoint1service

Comment: @Akanksha This helped me a lot! Do you have an update on this? Perhaps you could post the newest version of your approach for connecting to Cloud Endpoints from Angular 2 (including the wrappers you mentioned in the reply to the accepted answer)?

Comment: @jonasjuss I have posted the solution above. Hope it helps

Comment: @Akanksha Very helpful! Do you happen to have an example of calling action() from a component and returning an Observable / Promise for an array of items? I have a problem where my action() method returns undefined immediately, and cant get it to wait for the http response and return Observable or Promise with the items.

Comment: @jonasjuss you will have to provide callback. It is recommended that you do not use gapi as it does not return observable. You should use HttpModule of Angular 2 to request data from google endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are singletons by default. You should `provide` it in your AppModule, and then it will be available to all of your components. Just make sure to include it in your component constructors.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing'; 
import { GoogleService } from './google.service'; // important

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent],
    providers: [ GoogleService ], // important
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent],
})
export class  AppModule {
}
```

To make an endpoint available outside of your service, you can use the `public` keyword in front of the function that calls the endpoint. To call the endpoint in angular2, you can use the built-in `http` service from `@angular/http`. Here's an example service (only using HTTP GET) that will return an Observable for the endpoints you call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public endpoint1(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("http://endpoint.one.com");
    }

    public endpoint2(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("http://endpoint.two.com");
    }

}
```

You can then use the service like this in your component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleService } from './google.service'; // important

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private googleService: GoogleService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.googleService.endpoint1().subscribe(callback1, handleError);

        this.googleService.endpoint2().subscribe(callback2, handleError);

    }

    callback1(data){
        // do something with the data from ONE
    }

    callback2(data){
        // do something with the data from TWO
    }

    handleError(error: any){
        console.error(error);
    }

}
```

I recommend reading up a bit on using Observables in [this post](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) from Angular University.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating wrappers for each of those end points. Your sample pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think modifying the DOM to load gapi is particularly good practice. It's probably better to use `gapi` and `gapi.auth` TypeScript definitions by installing them with NPM.

I've posted instructions on how to do this in my answer to [Import gapi.auth2 in angular 2 typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091215/import-gapi-auth2-in-angular-2-typescript/).

Comment: I agree. I ended up creating my own service which hits google auth url and gets access token.