# Angular 2+ Error: Cannot find name 'gapi'

Tags: angular, google-analytics-api

Basically, I am receiving the error below when I call the google analytics api for core reporting data. It works on my localhost server but when I try to deploy the app, it fails for me. Please advise on how to import the "gapi" variable in angular2+. Many thanks!

This is how I call it in my angular app.
   gapi.auth.authorize(authData, (res:any)=>{})

ERROR in src/app/order/order.component.ts(65,7): error TS2304: Cannot 
   find name 'gapi'.
   src/app/order/order.component.ts(66,11): error TS2304: Cannot find 
   name 'gapi'.
   src/app/order/order.component.ts(67,11): error TS2304: Cannot find 
   name 'gapi'.
   src/app/order/order.component.ts(69,13): error TS2304: Cannot find 
   name 'gapi'.
   src/app/order/order.component.ts(71,15): error TS2304: Cannot find 
   name 'gapi'.
   src/app/order/order.component.ts(77,17): error TS2304: Cannot find 
   name 'gapi'.

Below are my codes

```
gapi.auth.authorize(authData, (res:any)=>{
      gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {
      gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then( (accountResponse:any) =>{
        let accountId = accountResponse.result.items[4].id;
        gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list({'accountId': accountId})
        .then((accountPropertiesResponse:any) => {
          gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
              'accountId': accountPropertiesResponse.result.items[0].accountId,
              'webPropertyId': accountPropertiesResponse.result.items[0].id,
          })
          .then((profileIdResponse:any)=>{

            gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
              'ids': 'ga:' + profileIdResponse.result.items[0].id,
              'start-date': sevenDaysAgo,
              'end-date': databaseDate,
              'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
              'dimensions': 'ga:deviceCategory',
            }).then((coreReportResponse:any)=>{
              mobileNum = coreReportResponse.result.rows[1][1];
              desktopNum = coreReportResponse.result.rows[0][1];
              tabletNum = coreReportResponse.result.rows[2][1];
              visits = coreReportResponse.result.totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions'];
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>ShopifyReport</title>
 <base href="/">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize" 
async defer></script>

  </body>
      </html>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
    ],
    "types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2", "gapi.auth"],
     "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
 }
```

Comment: Let me know if need to include module as well

Comment: DId you import gapi in your component? import * from 'gapi' ?

Comment: Or if you are really stuck and nothing works, you can add `declare var gapi : any;` in your component file

Comment: Tried both way. No good. I tried including it in the tsconfig.app.json now and it returns the following error for me now. ERROR in src/app/order/order.component.ts(70,23): error TS2339: Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.

Comment: Thank you! the declare var gapi: any; method did remove the error(Made a typo earlier when I tried it and I tried again). I am able to deploy the project now. However, I am facing another issue now. My deployed project is not calling the gapi code I have above, thus, not getting any data from google analytics for my post to my report model. Please advise!

Comment: declaring gapi as any will not have any effect on your code's logic. It'll just let typescript compile the component without throwing an error. You need to debug to check if the api lib is correctly imported and called

Comment: Nevermind, I just need to allow access from my google analytics side. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added the following code to the component and allowed access from Google Analytics for deploy link. Thank you all!

```
declare var gapi : any;
```

Answer (score 9):

For those who maybe having similar issues, the use of `NgZone` will solve the problem, follow these steps:

Install the following.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

In `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` within `compilerOptions` section add this `"gapi", "gapi.auth2"` to `types`. It will look like

```
"types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2"],
```

Then in you service or component, use `NgZone`, you import it from `@angular/core`

Here is example:

```
import { Component, NgZone, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-app',
  templateUrl: './google-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-app.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleAppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
        // example to render login button
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        ...
        ...
        });

        // example to load client
        gapi.load('client', {
         ...
         ...
        });

    });
  }    
}
```

Angular NgZone documentation... [read more](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

In **index.html**, depending what you want, you may need to add the following within the `<head></head>` tag

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: definetely in Angular 9 it need to be added in `tsconfig.app.json`

Answer (score 1):

To use gapi a with Angular, install the type script definitions using NPM.

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
```

also try adding to your compilerOptions:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "types": ["gapi"]
}
```

Comment: I did already, but it still have this error when I run ng build --prod. So should I import it on my component?

Comment: try adding to your compiler options as above

Comment: Did that already too. Please see post for that as well. Thanks!

Comment: try adding both. gapi and gapi.auth

Comment: Tried that, but this time, the localhost fail to compile and with same errors. "types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth"],

Comment: Should I post my codes as well? If so, please let me know

Comment: Same as the ones that I posted

Comment: ERROR in src/app/order/order.component.ts(65,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.
src/app/order/order.component.ts(66,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.
src/app/order/order.component.ts(67,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.
src/app/order/order.component.ts(69,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.
src/app/order/order.component.ts(71,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.
src/app/order/order.component.ts(77,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gapi'.

Comment: consider setting "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],

Comment: If I put the following code in - import "gapi", I get the following error -
Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.

Comment: Tried including the types and typeRoots in tsconfig.app.json now and it returns the following error. ERROR in src/app/order/order.component.ts(70,23): error TS2339: Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.

Comment: have you added   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize" async defer></script>
 to the index html?

Comment: I did. Receiving error TS2339: Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'typeof client now. I placed the script under the app-root tag

Comment: Hi, I used the declare var gapi: any; method and it removed the error. I am able to deploy the project now. However, I am facing another issue now. My deployed project is not calling the gapi code I have above, thus, not getting any data from google analytics for my post to my report model. Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution with type definitions have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782430/8471295) from Jack:

The part you and I were missing is the [tripe-slash-directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) telling the compiler where it needs to look up the gapi type information.

Either do this by providing the [reference path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-) directly to the file with the type description. (From Jack's answer in the linked post above)

```
// You may not have this explicit reference.
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/gapi/index.d.ts" />
```

Or use [reference types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-) to reference an @types package

```
/// <reference types="gapi" />
```

You will have to add this reference to every ts file that contains a reference to gapi.