# GAPI and Angular 7 issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have request to google drive using gapi:

```
getFolders(folderId: string): Observable<{ id: string, name: string }[]> {
    const promise = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      fields: 'incompleteSearch,nextPageToken,files(id,name)',
      q: `'${folderId}' in parents`,
    }).then((res) => {
      return JSON.parse(res.result.files);
    });
    return from(promise);
  }
```

then I try to show this data in component:
.ts file `ngOnInit`:

```
this.data$ = this.googleDriveService.getFolders(rootFolderId)
        .pipe(
          map((files) => {
            debugger;
            return files.map(file => ({ id: file.id, header: file.name, content: '', imageUrl: this.defaultImageUrl }));
          }),
          takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        );
```

and html file:

```
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let elem of (data$ | async)">
    <app-card (input)="returnCartItem(elem)" (click)="goto(elem.header, elem.id)"></app-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```

The problem is that `data$` always empty. I added `debugger` to `map` to check maybe something wrong with there, but it never goes in `map` function. From response, I get 2 files, so `res.result.files` isn't empty;

Comment: Did you mean to have single quotes around `'${folderId}'`?

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC, unfortunately no, the problem is that I send request, get a response (non-empty), but it is not displayed, because of `data$` - empty

Comment: When you're using the `async pipe` you don't need `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` as the `async pipe` takes care of unsubscribing for you.

Comment: @fridoo thx for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in gapi (google API). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091215/import-gapi-auth2-in-angular-2-typescript)
I created private method inObservable

```
private inObservable(promise) {
    return from(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          promise.then(resolve, reject);
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

And wrap my request into it

```
const promise = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      fields: 'incompleteSearch,nextPageToken,files(id,name)',
      q: `'${folderId}' in parents`,
    }).then((res) => {
      return JSON.parse(res.result.files);
    });
return inObservable(promise);
```

Answer (score 0):

You turned `getFolders()` into an observable, so you have to subscribe to it to start getting data from it.

```
this.googleDriveService.getFolders(rootFolderId).pipe(...).subscribe();
```

Comment: He's using the `async` pipe which takes care of the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem the way async is used, please try this:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let elem of data$ | async">
    <app-card (input)="returnCartItem(elem)" (click)="goto(elem.header, elem.id)"></app-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: I added `subscribe`, but still get nothing. Then import `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` and run in `subscribe`: `this.cdr.detectChanges();` After this angular rerender my component with data. So, it's my temporarily workaround, but to to fix it I have no idea

Comment: ts file: https://ghostbin.com/paste/j8wu6   html file: https://ghostbin.com/paste/mujx7

Comment: I use google api and I change app.module ts file: https://ghostbin.com/paste/usqdj maybe something wrong with him?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? How do you know that google session is established. Can you please put a log in initClient method and see if that gets triggered.

Comment: I use `tap(console.log)` to log response after map and I get an array with 2 items

Comment: It seems takeUntil is the culprit then. Can you please remove takeUntil and just use take(1) to see if the code inside subscription executes?

Comment: The problem was in google drive api (gapi). I'll add more description as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that due to your async pipe, the inner elements are tried to be rendered before the async data is loaded. You can do a simple workaround to give your async data a reference variable and render the inner contents once the reference variable is ready as

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let elem of data | async">  //note it is not data$
        <app-card (input)="returnCartItem(elem)" (click)="goto(elem.header, elem.id)"> 
        </app-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</ng-container
```